# How often does Parallel.For invoke localInit?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I've been experimenting with Parallel.For. In particular, overloads that support thread-local data such as

> public static System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopResult For (long fromInclusive, long toExclusive, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Func localInit, Func body, Action localFinally);

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For__1_System_Int64_System_Int64_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_System_Func___0__System_Func_System_Int64_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState___0___0__System_Action___0__)

> The localInit delegate is invoked once for each thread that participates in the loop's execution

However I think my example below contradicts it

```
var threads = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
ValueTuple LocalInit()
{
    threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    return new System.ValueTuple();
}
ValueTuple Body(long i, ParallelLoopState _, ValueTuple state) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    return state;
}
void LocalFinally(ValueTuple state) { };

Parallel.For(0L, 1000L, new ParallelOptions(), LocalInit, Body, LocalFinally);

Console.WriteLine($"{threads.Count} inits between {threads.Distinct().Count()} threads");
```

It prints a message such as

> 79 inits between 13 threads

What's going on?

Comment: You are *blocking* the threads, forcing `Parallel.For` to create more threads in order to process the input. The `Parallel.` methods are meant for data parallelism. They'll start with roughly as many tasks as there are cores and add more tasks if they detect the tasks are blocked.

Comment: A better example would be to use a large loop and  `Body` that actually does something or a Spinwait that doesn't put the thread to sleep

Answer (score 3):

Try recording task id `Task.CurrentId` instead of thread id.

```
var threads = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
ValueTuple LocalInit()
{
    threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    tasks.Add(Task.CurrentId ?? throw new Exception());
    return new System.ValueTuple();
}
ValueTuple Body(long i, ParallelLoopState _, ValueTuple state) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    return state;
}
void LocalFinally(ValueTuple state) { };

Parallel.For(0L, 1000L, new ParallelOptions(), LocalInit, Body, LocalFinally);

Console.WriteLine($"{threads.Count} inits between {threads.Distinct().Count()} threads");
Console.WriteLine($"{tasks.Count} inits between {tasks.Distinct().Count()} tasks");
```

This prints

> 87 inits between 16 threads
>   87 inits between 87 tasks

The docs are wrong. They should instead say

> The localInit delegate is invoked **once for each task** that participates in the loop's execution

There can be more tasks than threads. Always *number of threads* ≤ *number of tasks* ≤ *number of iterations*.

Comment: The problem is the code itself, not the documentation. It *stops* the thread, forcing `Parallel.` to use another one. It's already documented that `Parallel.` can use more tasks than cores if the tasks take too long

Comment: Yup - `Thread.Sleep(100)` shows 77 inits and 14 threads on an i7. `Thread.SpinWait(100)` shows 7/7

Comment: The code could block for other reasons as well, that may not be in the control of the developer. The point here is that there are 87 inits vs 16 threads. This is not explained by code blocking. What happens is that 16 distinct threads are reused to execute 87 tasks. `LocalInit()` is called once for each task not each thread, as explained in the answer. The design is reasonable (when a thread is reused it has to be reinitialized) but should it be documented properly.