# Persist variable on thread in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am looking to parallelise processing of a task which is dependent on an object (`State`), **which is not thread-safe, and whose construction is time-expensive**.

For this reason, I was looking into [partition-local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-foreach-loop-with-partition-local-variables), but either I am doing it wrong or looking for something else. This more or less represents my current implementation:

```cs
Parallel.ForEach<string, State>(folders, config, () => new State(), (source, loopState, index, threadState) =>
{
    var content = File.ReadAllText(source);        // read file
    var result = threadState.doSomething(content); // do something
    File.WriteAllText(outputFile, result);         // write output
    return threadState;
}, (threadState) => { });
```

However, I have added a `Console.WriteLine` in my `State` initializer, and I see that for every iteration of the loop, the `State` constructor is called, resulting in a big performance hit. I would like the *instance* of `State` in one thread being passed to the subsequent iteration on that same thread.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `either I am doing it wrong` - you aren't, it's just [not documented very well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51748047/11683).

Comment: @GSerg it seems that in the meanwhile the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) have been updated, and the relevant information is now correct: *"The localInit delegate is invoked once for each **task** that participates in the loop's execution"* (emphasis added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. The simplest is to create a single `State` object, and synchronize it with the `lock` statement:

```
State state = new();

Parallel.ForEach(folders, parallelOptions, folder =>
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(folder);
    string result;
    lock (state) { result = state.DoSomething(content); }
    File.WriteAllText(outputFile, result);
});
```

I assume that this is not viable because the `DoSomething` method is time consuming, and synchronizing it will defeat the purpose of parallelization.

Another option is to use a [`ThreadLocal<State>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1). This class provides a thread-local storage of data, so the number of `State` objects created will be equal to the number of threads employed by the `Parallel.ForEach`.

```
using ThreadLocal<State> threadLocalState = new(() => new State());

Parallel.ForEach(folders, parallelOptions, folder =>
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(folder);
    string result = threadLocalState.Value.DoSomething(content);
    File.WriteAllText(outputFile, result);
});
```

This will probably create less `State` objects than the `Parallel.ForEach<TSource, TLocal>` overload, but still not equal to the configured `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. The `Parallel.ForEach` uses threads from the `ThreadPool`, and it is quite possible that it will use all of them during the calculation, provided that the list of `folders` is sufficiently long. And you have little control over the size of the `ThreadPool`. So this is not a particularly  enticing solution either.

The third and final option I can think of is to create a pool of `State` objects, and `Rent`/`Return` one in each loop:

```
ObjectPool<State> statePool = new(() => new State());

Parallel.ForEach(folders, parallelOptions, folder =>
{
    State state = statePool.Rent();
    string content = File.ReadAllText(folder);
    string result = state.DoSomething(content);
    File.WriteAllText(outputFile, result);
    statePool.Return(state);
});
```

This way the number of the instantiated `State` objects will be equal to the maximum degree of parallelism.

The only problem is that there is no `ObjectPool<T>` class in the standard .NET libraries (there is only an [`ArrayPool<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1) class), so you'll have to find one. Here is a simple implementation based on a [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1):

```
public class ObjectPool<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : new()
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<T> _bag = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
    private readonly Func<T> _factory;

    public ObjectPool(Func<T> factory = default) => _factory = factory;

    public T Rent()
    {
        if (_bag.TryTake(out T obj)) return obj;
        return _factory is not null ? _factory() : new T();
    }

    public void Return(T obj) => _bag.Add(obj);

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _bag.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

**Update:** An [`ObjectPool<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1) class exists in the [Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool/) package. It has a slightly different API than the custom `ObjectPool<T>` implementation shown above.