# How to setup parallel execution with a concurrency limit while also reusing a resource throughout each concurrent chain?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm trying to get my head around combining async enumerables with parallel execution in C# and I'm sure there are multiple techniques to approach my particular problem.

Basically, I have a large list of file paths that I want to process in parallel, but since my processing involves the use of a heavy class which is non-trivial to instantiate, I want to be able to reuse instances of this class instead of creating a new one for each iteration.

The `Parallel.ForEachAsync` can be used with the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option (via `ParallelOptions` class) which is pretty neat and close to what I'm looking for except that there doesn't seem to be a simple/safe way to reuse an instance from the outside.

Ideally, I could instantiate say 12 instances of this big class and process 12 chunks of my paths enumerable in parallel which each reuse a single instance of that class.

I was looking into using SemaphoreSlim or a partitioner, but maybe some more experienced C# folks might have suggestions?

EDIT:

It was noted that more specifics were needed on my particular problem, so I'll try and explain as close to the exact case that I'm working on.

Given a large (>1mil) list of image file paths, I'm trying to perform object detection on each image as efficiently as possible. The library I'm using makes use of `Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime` and exposes a class which once initialized, can invoke a method for predicting objects on an image given its path.

I have a limited lower level understanding of what is going on but from what I understand, the constructor for this library's class initializes some runtime session which prohibits safely using the instance in parallel (due to shared memory). I can use this instance asynchronously, but the instance cannot be used across concurrent operations.

Therefore, I was aiming to parallelize my problem by processing subsets/chunks of my paths in parallel where each concurrent operation is reusing an instance of the large library class. Ideally, I could eliminate the overhead of instantiating this class in each iteration.

Comment: *I want to be able to reuse instances of this class instead of creating a new one for each iteration*... then reuse... This question is to broad(or even to open) you didn't even mention what is stopping you from reusing

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added a bit more context hopefully without making the question too confusing

Comment: How about an object pool?

Comment: Related: [Persist variable on thread in C# Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64606942/persist-variable-on-thread-in-c-sharp-parallel-foreach).

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Func<TLocal>` parameter