# Awaitable collection of reuseable resources

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, collections, thread-safety

I have tried to search the web for this, but I didn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I have a list of workers, that execute certain work. In order to execute this work, the workers need access to resources. So I need a thread safe collection that manages access to resources. The resources are reusable, but can only be accessed by 1 task at a time. Here is a very minimalistic example of how this could work.

My mind is running in circles while trying to come up with a thread safe manner to do this.

```
public interface IResource
{
}

public class TestResource : IResource
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("printing");
    }
}

public class ResourcePool
{
    public async Task TryUseResource<T>(Action<T> callback,
        CancellationToken token = default) where T : IResource
    {
        // await and claim a resource that is not in use. 
        // execute the callback
        // unclaim the resource
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public async void ExecuteWork(ResourcePool pool)
    {
        await pool.TryUseResource<TestResource>((resource) =>
        {
            resource.Print();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any collection in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-7.0) namespace.

Comment: Related: [Persist variable on thread in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64606942/persist-variable-on-thread-in-parallel-foreach).

Comment: How is the number of workers and resources related? Are there more workers than resources, more resources than workers, or they are 1:1? Are all the resources created proactively upfront, or they are created on demand?

Answer (score -2):

I came up with the following:

```
public class AwaitableResources<T>
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> availableResources = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    public async Task<bool> TryUseResource(Action<T> callback,
        CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync(token);
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            if(availableResources.TryDequeue(out var resource))
            {
                try
                {
                    callback.Invoke(resource);
                    success = true;
                }
                finally
                {
                    availableResources.Enqueue(resource);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            success = false;
        return success;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You construct no resources and set a semaphore that cannot be used. 2. Why have a queue of resources if you're going to only allow one callback to run at a time anyway?  Even if you filled the queue you never use more than one at a time 3. If you don't have a resource you just don't run the operation, just dropping it on the floor, which is not what was asked for, the request is to wait for a resource.

Comment: 4. If the token is canceled you should let the returned task be canceled as well (rather than returning a boolean) which you can do by calling the throw if cancelled method on the token.  Also, it doesn't really make sense to cancel the task *after you already successfully finished* as you're indicating to the caller that the operation didn't run when it did in fact run.